# CMake: check for availability of static C++ libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I am trying to statically link a multi-threaded binary. It would be nice if CMake could warn that the static libraries are missing.

Note: I know that the solution is installing the static libraries (libstdc++-static and glibc-static in Fedora 31, if this is of help to anyone), I'd just prefer that the missing libraries are reported by CMake and not when building.

(As a side note, is there any nicer way to support static linking? At the moment I have some platform-dependent stuff to support it across our target systems, I have not found anything more portable...)

Here is a sample CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_link_options(-static)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(test)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE Threads::Threads)

target_sources(test PRIVATE test.cpp)
```

And here is the output:

```
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/sergio/src/static_cmake/build
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target test
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make:101: test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:93: CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:101: all] Error 2
```

Comment: `find_library(libpthread.a)`?

Answer (score 1):

As commented, one way to produce an error for a missing library in CMake (before compilation/linking) is to use [`find_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html). If CMake cannot find the specific library, an error will occur when you use the library variable:

```
# Define a variable my_pthread_static_lib to store the library, if found.
find_library(my_pthread_static_lib libpthread.a)

add_executable(test)
# Error will occur here during CMake configuration, if not found
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE ${my_pthread_static_lib})
```

This error will appear if `my_pthread_static_lib` library is not found:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
my_pthread_static_lib
    linked by target "test" in directory /path/to/CMake/file
```

Comment: Thank you. So there does not seem to be any portable way to do this...

Comment: @SergioLosilla I think it would depend on the library. There may be some libraries `XXX` in which the `find_package(XXX ...)` call provides a **separate** imported target for the static libraries (e.g. `XXX::XXX_static`). In this case, you can simply use that provided target `XXX::XXX_static` in `target_link_libraries()` to check for existence of the library.

Comment: The problem is two-fold in this particular case: FindThreads does not seem to provide that, and the C++ standard/runtime libraries do not require a specific find_package call.